Can we open native apps from flutter inapp-webview
I have created a flutter app which uses Azure ADB2C for login, this login screen in displayed as webview in flutter app.
Once successful login user has to authenticate using Microsoft authenticator app.
Here a URL is generated to open authenticator app which looks like this
otpauth://totp/B2CDev:*****?secret=asdfasdfasdf&issuer=B2CDev
But when clicked on the link it throws error as 'ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME'.

Is it possible to communicate to android native apps from flutter inapp-webview ? Is there any other approach to achieve this ?

can you include sample snippet?

You can Use url_launcher
launchUrl(Uri.parse(url),mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);


It works with url_launcher when trigger from flutter app but will it open the authenticator app from webview since link to open authenticator app is available inside webview itself
